# Fire trigger allows only transaction done at monday to saturday in PLSQL Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
create or replace trigger tri_hours
before insert 
on dept
begin

    if (to_char(sysdate,'day')='sunday') then
    raise_application_error(-20001,' Insert  Opeartion  not allow because today is sunday  ');
    else
        if inserting then
                --insert query on table dept
        end if;     
    end if;
end;
/
```

When i am try to insert a new record on sunday then trigger does not work.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: In above code please ignore raise_application_error(-20001,'INSERT DURING 09 TO 18  '); and then consider raise_application_error(-20001,'Insert operation allow only in between Monday to Saturday');

Comment: My Question is i am fire a trigger when user insert a new record when sunday.

Comment: Please edit your question rather than posting changes in comments.  I still don't see a question.  You have a problem.  You've written some code.  Does the code solve the problem?  Are you getting an error?  If so, what error?

Comment: See my problem:-----------------------------                   create or replace trigger tri_hours
before insert 
on dept
begin

 if (to_char(sysdate,'day')='sunday') then
 raise_application_error(-20001,' Insert  Opeartion  not allow because today is sunday  ');
 else
  if inserting then
    dbms_output.put_line(to_char(sysdate,'HH24'));
  end if;  
 end if;
end;
/

Comment: When i am try to insert a new record on Friday then trigger does not work.

Comment: I've edited the question and added your last comment to it. This comment is the first indication you've provided of what the problem is. Now, what do you mean by "does not work"? DO NOT LEAVE ANOTHER COMMENT - edit the question and explain what you mean by "does not work". To edit the question click on the word 'edit' which appears beneath the [plsql] tag below the question text. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `day` date format mask with `to_char` results in a string that is padded to nine characters with spaces. You need to strip the spaces with the `fm` format mask i.e.

```
if (to_char(sysdate,'fmday') = 'sunday') then
```